# How to override string serialization in ServiceStack.Text?

Tags: servicestack

How come the following works to override Guid formatting:

```
ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig<Guid>.SerializeFn = guid => guid.ToString();
```

But doing this to force null strings to empty strings doesn't?

```
ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig<string>.SerializeFn = str => str ?? string.Empty;
```

I have this enabled:

```
ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.IncludeNullValues = true;
```

I have also tried the *String* class rather than the *string* primitive. And the raw version named .RawSerializeFn

Is there a different work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String's are specially handled in [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) so you can't override their behavior with configuration.

Given you can't override it, the only solution I can see (other than submitting a pull-request) is to reflect over the model and populate null properties with empty strings.

Comment: Is there a standard way to do this for all responses? As ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig<T>.OnSerializingFn looks like it'd need to be configured for every response DTO.

Comment: Unfortunately those would need to be called for each DTO, so you would need some reflection to reflect over all types. [Raise an issue](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/issues) if you want to see configurable support for emitting null strings as empty strings

Comment: Ok posted it as an issue. For now using a utility function on the client side to recursively replace nulls with "", but of course it wont work when I encounter nullables that aren't strings in my schema.